# When calling GCHandle.Alloc on a class, will it also pin members of that class?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Suppose I have a class that has a few references to other classes:

```
class Bar {

}

class Baz {

}

class Foo {
    Bar bar;
    Baz baz;
}
```

Then I'm calling `GCHandle.Alloc` on an instance of that class:

```
var foo = new Foo() { bar = new Bar(), baz = new Baz() };
var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(foo, GCHandleType.Normal);
```

Then I'm passing the `handle` to native code which passes it back to C# in a callback function.
C# code will access both `bar` and `baz` members.
Will pinning `foo` also guarantee that `bar` and `baz` are also pinned or should I pin them explicitly?

Follow up question assuming that I need to pin `bar` and `baz` explicitly:

Suppose I'd like to pin an object which I'm not the author of its class (also assume that the object has a few private members).
How can I pin that object so it remains in usable (meaning, non of its members were collected by the GC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are not pinning `foo`. To pin it you'd have to use `GCHandleType.Pinned`. This would prevent GC to move the pinned object in memory and will allow to reach object directly using a handle (so handle will basically represent pointer to that object in memory). But it's not necessary in this case because native code does not use the handle - it passes it back to managed code. So you correctly using `Normal` handle (which again does not pin the object). Also as correctly mentioned in comments - you won't be able to pin `foo` anyway, because only objects with only [blittable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) members can be pinned.

So only thing this `Normal` handle does is it prevents object from garbage collection, and allows you to refer to this object inderectly using handle from managed code (in this case from your callback function). So handle itself is not a pointer to managed object, but can be used to reach that object from managed code (using `handle.Target`).

As such, because `Foo` cannot be collected, then `bar` and `baz` cannot be collected either, so you don't need to do anything about them.

Comment: Also note that you cannot pin an object which contains non-blittable members.